# gsoap adding "custom/chrono_time_point.h" "WARNING": missing ';' or invalid type specified

Tags: gsoap

after uncommenting in typemap.dat the following line:

```
xsd__dateTime = #import "custom/chrono_time_point.h" | xsd__dateTime
```

I run wsdl2h and everything is fine..

but later in soapcpp2 I'm getting the following warning:

```
custom/chrono_time_point.h(70): *WARNING*: invalid type specified (missing ';' or type name used as non-type identifier?)
```

what is this?

## Edit

I use gsoap windows from vcpkg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to `#include "custom/chrono_time_point.h"` in your code base after adding that line to your `typemap.dat`. Adding this line suffices to use `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` for XML `xsd:dateTime` values.

Note that `#import custom/chrono_time_point.h` is used by soapcpp2 to register the `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` serializer.

The serialization implementation is `custom/chrono_time_point.cpp` which should also be compiled together with the project.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. anyway, I didn't include nothing inside the output file, but merely edited the typemap.dat file as you say. the soapcpp2 outputs: 
 custom/chrono_time_point.h(70): *WARNING*: invalid type specified (missing ';' or type name used as non-type identifier?)
Do you have an idea why it does that? I'm using the latest windows version from vcpkg

Comment: For soapcpp2 make sure to use `soapcpp2 -c++11` to support c++11.

Comment: Running soapcpp2 on the file works fine, no issues: `soapcpp2 -c++11 custom/chrono_time_point.h` does not produce an error. So something else is happening if you get errors.

Comment: sorry for the late response. since yesterday I'm trying to compile gsoap on windows (didn't see any pre-compiled binaries). anyway, my speculation is that the gsoap files that I download with vcpkg doing the problem. (assuming your OS is windows 10 and assuming it works just fine as you are saying) so I will try to work without vcpkg and I will update you.  very frustrating !

Comment: by the way. I am generating the files with -c++11; both in wsdl2h.exe and soapcpp2.exe...

Comment: ok, so building gsoap with MSVC myself did solve the problem. now, there is no error anymore. which means that the problem was with the vcpkg gsoap triplet